# ui_* files are not generated by QT5.5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, moc, qt5.5

I want to use framework generated by compiling QT5 source on MAC in a QT5 application.

If I have the following in my `.pro` file then `ui_*` files are not generated.

```
QT -= gui core network widgets
```

How to generate these `ui_*` files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having issues in using frameworks from custom location (these are compiled from qt source on MAC), qmake is adding some include switches (`-I/path/to/Qt5.5/install/location/QtCore.framework`) that i cannot get rid of without `QT -= widgets gui`.

I know the issue is somewhere else but as far as this question goes the answer i was looking was is:

`CONFIG += uic3`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should replace "QT -=" to "QT +=" ?